# Is there a way to send a message to a specific user in the bot.on("ready") function?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to get my bot to send me a direct message when it gets online/is ready

I've tried to use functions such as `bot.guilds.members.find("id", "my id")` 
and `bot.guilds.members.get("id", "my id")` but it just returns find/get is not a function

```
bot.on("ready", async message => {
    bot.guilds.members.find("id", "my id") 
});
```

I want the bot to send me a message when it comes online

Comment: i need it to do it on start up though not on a message and you cant gather a guild from message on start up

Answer (score 1):

```js
bot.on("ready", async () => {
    bot.users.get("Your ID").send("Message")
});
```

Comment: i just get the error of "cannot read property 'channel' of undefined

Comment: In your code snippet, wouldn't the `async` be redundant and the unprovided `message` parameter always be undefined?

Comment: Maybe he uses it for something else

Answer (score 0):

The [ready event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-ready) does not provide any arguments (I hope that's the right way to phrase that). So your callback function's `message` parameter is `undefined`, and attempting to read `message.channel` gives you that "cannot read property 'channel' of undefined" error.

This should work:

```
const Client = new Discord.Client();
Client.login("YOUR TOKEN");

Client.on("ready", async () => {
    let botDev = await Client.fetchUser("YOUR ID");
    botDev.send("YOUR PRIVATE MESSAGE");
});
```